# How to match elements from one set to elements in another set using Firebase?

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I recently started to learn Android and I came across a problem. I want to create a code for Firebase (*the database I am using to store values*) such that the contents from one set are matched to elements in another set.

The scenario is as follows: there is a student who wants to learn or is interested in learning a new skill (*C/C++, drawing, music, etc.*), if he were to update them in their profile, he should get suggestions as names of other users registered in the application who have already listed their skill set.

It is much like how Facebook suggests common friends, but here, the basis for suggestion is what skills the user has and what he wants to learn.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service Here at SO we fix your attempts, we do not code things for you

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the same thing for one of my apps. I'll write about what I did to achieve that

First of all, you need to design your Realtime Database structure in a way to achieve that.

Example of a Individual User node in your database at firebase could be like

```
User
 - Personal Details
   - First name
   - last name
   - Dob 
 - Interests (values like "music,movies,sports") //Separated by a comma 
 - ...
```

Now lets say User A likes "music" and that you need to suggest him other users who likes music too, In this case what you can do is retrieve all the users who have interests "music" in their profile.

```
reference.addChildEventListener()
```

In here,inside the `onChildAdded()` you can compare to see if the Interest of a particular user has music in it. (if it does, add that user to your arraylist for your recyclerview to display it.)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try it out and let you know the results.